# How to set universal variable values in one fragment and access it in another while using NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, fragment, navigation-drawer, communication, android-fragmentactivity

I am working on a simple project with NavigationDrawer in Android. The drawer has three items Game, Settings, About Us. The app loads the Game fragment first. Let us say in the Settings fragment there is on control to select the Level. Say I select level 3. Now whenever I go to Games fragment again the game should be loaded with Level 3.

Using interfaces and implementing the methods calls the Game fragment immediately. What if i have other settings to change? I want the Game with level 3 only when I click Game in the drawer.

Please help!!!

You can find the image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXxFO.png